# Wann kann man "sehr viel" benutzen?

Tags: grammar, adverb

Ich habe diesen Satz gelesen:

> Ich habe sehr viel Spaß gehabt

Wann ist es möglich, *sehr* + *viel* zusammen zu benutzen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wir haben hier eine Steigerungsform, die recht universell anzuwenden ist:

> Wir haben Spaghetti gegessen.
>
> Wir haben dünne Spaghetti gegessen.
>
> Wir haben sehr dünne Spaghetti gegessen.

Mir fällt, ehrlich gesagt, gerade kein Beispiel ein, wo man das nicht verwenden kann. Im Italienischen wäre meiner bescheidenen Meinung nach "molto" das Äquivalent.

Vielleicht schreibst du deine Frage um: Wann kann man "sehr" **nicht** zur Steigerung einsetzen?

Comment: So, since sehr and viel both mean "molto/much" (I know they're not equivalent). Is it simply that you reinforce the adverb "viel" with "sehr", so that "sehr viel" is a reiforcement of the simple "viel" here?

Comment: @martina Genau so. Es wird mir jetzt erst klar, daß "molto" "viel" heißt, aber wie "sehr" verwendet wird, so daß "viel" und "sehr viel" von Google beides mit "molto" übersetzt wird. Wie unterscheidet ihr das?

Comment: Du sagst: "es regnet viel"; aber "ich bin sehr traurig" (aud italienisch würdest du "molto" in die beide Satzen benutzen), also, ich denke, "sehr" geht vor einen Adjektiv, "viel" (adverb) geht wenn keinen Namen gibt.

Comment: @Martina Richtig, *sehr* geht vor jedem Adjektiv, ob es Sinn ergibt, ist eine andere Frage (siehe Lars' Antwort). *Viel* benutzt du, wenn es um Mengenangaben geht (viel Schnee, viel Regen, viel Glück, viel Geld, usw. man kann zum Test "eine große Menge" einsetzen: "eine große Menge Regen", "es regnet große Mengen" - beides geht, daher kann dort "viel" stehen). Aber wenn jemand "viel gut" oder "viel lang" sagt, kann man seine Herkunft leicht erraten :)

Comment: Wonderful, I've got it: sehr viel is the superlative of viel, that is, "moltissimo" in Italian. Thank you!

Comment: @martina, the superlative of *viel* is actually *am meisten* (the comparative is *more*), *sehr viel* is just *very much*.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz You mean *mehr*, not *more*. Sehr viel mehr mag ich nicht dazu sagen ....

Comment: @Ingo, sorry and thanks, I mixed languages.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz No worries! Also consider: "Ich habe wenig Geld. Meine Frau hat mehr." does *not* mean she has much. If I wrote "Meine Frau hingegen hat viel." it would mean she had more than just more than I have ....

Answer (score 2):

Absolute *(tot, lebendig, dreieckig etc.)* sowie bereits den geringsten beziehungsweise höchsten Grad angebende Adjektive *(minimal, maximal, extrem etc.)* können nicht gesteigert werden.

Comment: Dieses Statement finde ich schon *sehr extrem*. Habe gehört, es gibt Katzen die haben einen *sehr dreieckigen* Kopf. Zugegeben, die Sprache wird dabei schon *sehr maximal* ausgereizt, aber die Sprache lebt – Ich meine, sie ist *sehr lebendig*.

Comment: Grammatikalisch lassen sich zweifelsfrei auch die genannten Adjektive steigern, wenngleich der Elativ im Deutschen aber nur umgangssprachlich von Bedeutung sein dürfte.

Answer (score 2):

Aufpassen muss man bei negierten Adjektiven:

> Er ist nicht mehr lebendig.
>
> Er ist nicht mehr sehr lebendig.

Hier bewirkt das "sehr" effektiv eine *Abschwächung* der Aussage.